# Why is the cardinality of a language defined as $||\mathcal{L}||$?

Tags: model-theory

I'm reading Chang and Keisler's Model Theory and I don't quite understand the notation they use for the cardinality of a language.

Elsewhere in the book, the cardinality of a set $X$ is denoted by $|X|$. Such as in p.21 where they talk about the cardinality of a model $\mathcal{A}$ being the cardinality $|A|$ of its universe $A$. (I checked, a similar usual notation is found in the Set Theory appendix of  the book, where a cardinal definition is to be found).

What I don't understand is the following notation (section 1.3, p.19) of the cardinal of a language $\mathcal{L}$ :

$||\mathcal{L}|| = \omega \cup |\mathcal{L}|$

If the cardinal of a language is $||\mathcal{L}||$, then what is $|\mathcal{L}|$ ?

And why does it have a cardinality of at least $\omega$ ? I guess this has to do number of variables. But then again, what would $|\mathcal{L}|$ be ? It's not clear to me. I guess $|\mathcal{L}|$ could be the cardinality of the set of symbols of $\mathcal{L}$, but isn't that precisely what the cardinality of $\mathcal{L}$ is supposed to be ? In which case, why do they decide to denote it by $||\mathcal{L}||$ ?

Comment: I don't have the book here, but seem to recall $|L|$ was the cardinality of the set of non-logical symbols. There is no real point, makes a slightly tighter statement of Loweheim-skolem and a few other results.

Comment: One simple reason is that defined this way, the number of formulas (expressions, really) over $\mathcal{L}$ is equal to $\| \mathcal{L} \|$ (instead of $| \mathcal{L} | + \omega$). This makes the statements of some theorems (such as that mentioned by André above) a little more succinct. They probably decided to use $\| \cdot \|$ so as to not overload the $| \cdot |$ symbol (which I think is used in the normal meaning in the text).

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by Arthur Fischer, $\rVert \mathcal L\rVert$ is the number of (first order) formulas in $\mathcal L$.

From my experience, I've seen $\lvert \mathcal L\rvert$ used to denote what is denoted here as $\lVert \mathcal L\rVert$ (i.e. the cardinality of the set of formulas).

This vagueness originates, I think, from simple convenience (as mentioned in the comments) *and* from the blurred distinction between languages (as sets of formulas) and signatures in first order logic.

It is also kind of similar to how we sometimes denote by $\lvert M\rvert$ the cardinality of the universe of a model $M$, instead of writing $\lVert M\rVert$, which is technically the correct way to denote it – this is because we often denote by $M$ both the model and its universe, which we could denote by $\lvert M\rvert$ if we wanted to be more precise, or else we could denote the model by $\mathfrak M$ and the universe by $M$ – but both of these conventions are bothersome, and confusion they might avert is unlikely, anyway.