# The definition of the cardinality of a signature

Tags: logic, model-theory

*Model Theory* by Wilfrid Hodges gives the following definition of the cardinality of a signature.

> For many purposes we shall need to know the cardinal of the structure $\langle Y \rangle_B$. This can be estimated as follows.We define the **cardinality** of $L$, in symbols $|L|$, to be the least infinite cardinal $\ge$ the number of symbols in $L$.

Can anyone elaborate on what "the least infinite cardinal $\ge$ the number of symbols in $L$" mean? What is the cardinality of a signature in the end?

Comment: The signature is a set of "symbols". The cardinality is just asking how big that set of symbols is.

Answer (score 4):

I should remark that the following terminology varies with authors, for example, in Chang and Keisler's *Model Theory*, the term 'signature' is never used. Some authors  do not take into account the logical vocabulary, because they take it already fixed across languages, etc. However, I find it a clearer practice to distinctly incorporate the terms all, which is quite helpful outside mathematics as well.

The cardinality of a (formal) language $\mathcal{L}$ is effectively the cardinality of the set of wffs (well-formed formulas) expressible in the language $\mathcal{L}$. For example, the cardinality of the language of the standard first-order predicate logic is countably infinite. I shall expand on this below.

The cardinality of a signature $\sigma$ (the non-logical vocabulary of a language $\mathcal{L}$) is the cardinality of the set of symbols in the signature $\sigma$. For example, the signature of the structure $\mathcal{N}=\langle\mathbb{N}, 0, 1, +, \cdot, <\rangle$ has a cardinality of 5.

The cardinality of a structure is equal to the cardinality of its domain (universe). Thus, the structure of the foregoing example has the cardinality of $\vert\mathbb{N}\vert = \aleph_{0}$.

Returning to Hodges' definition of the cardinality of a language:

> the cardinality of $\mathcal{L}$, in symbols $\vert\mathcal{L}\vert$
> is the least infinite cardinal $≥$ the number of symbols in $\mathcal{L}$

In Chang and Keisler's *Model Theory* (p. 19), the cardinality of a language is formulated as

$$\Vert\mathcal{L}\Vert = \omega\cup\vert\mathcal{L}\vert,$$

in which $\mathcal{L}$ is substituted for the present usage of signature, employing a sum of ordinal numbers, which might be more informative and useful.

Skipping over the shortcut terminologies of both books (one reason Chang and Keisler's book resorts to the symbol $\Vert .\Vert$, see [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833665/why-is-the-cardinality-of-a-language-defined-as-mathcall)), an explicit formulation of the idea is

$$\vert\mathcal{L}\vert = max(\vert\sigma\vert, \aleph_{0})$$

Notice that the former also one fulfils the same idea: The cardinality of the language is that of which is the larger. We may make sense of the occurrence of $\aleph_{0}$ (or $\omega$) considering a 1-1 correspondence of each wff to a natural number when the signature is finite.